# Inner class as a part of an outer class

Tags: java, inner-classes

Let's suppose that I have a shop of toys. And I have a web page where these toys can be bought. Each toy has its own features but to represent a human toy I have a class called `HumanToy` with some properties like height, weight.... But I have a nested property that it itself a JavaBean called `HumanLegs` and this class has its own features like:

```
public class HumanToy {     

    private Double height;
    private Double weight;

    private HumanLegs humanLegs;

    private class HumanLegs {

        private Double height;
        private Double weight;
    }
```

My question would be:

Does it make any sense that this toy has a static `HumanLegs` class? I mean, conceptually, `HumanLegs` cannot exist by its own, they only exist with a toy so I think its logical that this is an inner class at first (not a separated class), and secondly not static for the same reason, I mean, only instantiating a `HumanToy` you can get a `HumanLegs` object or to get a `HumanLegs` object you need a `HumanToy` object. Is this the right thinking?

Comment: Sure, if they cannot be separated in your conceptualized world, then this is exactly the right thinking. Remark: don't use the object wrappers for `double` if you don't have to. The `HumanLegs` member field should be written `humanLegs`. Nowadays a lot of people prefer immutable objects and builders over mutable beans, by the way. Oh, and you could just call it `Legs` I suppose, and reference it as `HumanToy.Legs`.

Comment: Yup.  Makes perfect sense.  If you want to share code between `HumanToyLeg` and `RobotToyLeg` then, of course, they are free to implement / extend the `ToyLeg` interface / class

Answer (score 3):

Yes it makes sense because `HumanLegs` keeps a reference to his outer class.
If you move the instance of `HumanLegs` to an other instance of `HumanToy` the originating `HumanToy` will not be deleted because `HumanLegs` does keep a reference to it.

The outerclass is thus kept in memory for at least as long as all instances of the innerclass.

Comment: The outer class is not allowed to leg it :)